# Is there a moment where two objects share the same velocity during an elastic collision?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, momentum, collision

If two objects undergo an elastic collision is there a moment during the collision where the two objects share the same velocity? According to my physics course there is a moment like this. I can't seem to grasp it. Is this true, if yes why?

Comment: You need to specify what point is to be used as shared reference of velocity. One candidate is to take the common center of mass of the two objects, but obviously that is not the only candidate.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the problem from the center-of-momentum frame, with axes chosen so that the initial momenta lie on the x axis.

In a symmetric head-on collision in which the momenta stay on the x axis at all times, by the intermediate value theorem there's an instant when the momentum of one of the objects is zero. Because the sum of the momenta is always zero, the momentum of the other object is zero at the same instant.

In a less symmetric collision, once the objects start to interact, they'll have nonzero and opposite momenta in the y and/or z directions, so their velocities will never be equal.